# How to save blob as webm on node.js

Tags: node.js, blob, multipartform-data, webm, data-url

I am recording a video in chrome using [RecordRTC.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC) and then sends the generated blob to node.js server using enctype='multipart/form-data'.

When i send a post request by converting blob as dataURL,

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZMbygbTah7gTAgUa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

1encof615fpyoj85bzwo.webm
------WebKitFormBoundaryZMbygbTah7gTAgUa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

video/webm
------WebKitFormBoundaryZMbygbTah7gTAgUa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contents"

data:video/webm;base64,GkXfo0AgQoaBAUL3gQFC8oEEQvOBCEKCQAR3ZWJtQoeBA...
------WebKitFormBoundaryZMbygbTah7gTAgUa--
```

It Works fine. Except when the data is large, video is not saved properly. Maybe, because whole content might not get transferred due to large size.

So, I tried to send the blob as input type file, but the saved video seems corrupted as it does not play.

The sent blob, when printed on server, is something like this:

```
Eߣ@ B��B��B��B�B�@webmB��B��S�g�fI�f@(*ױ@B@M�@whammyWA@whammyD�@žT�k@5�@2ׁsŁ��"�...
```

The Server side code is:

```
function upload(response, file) {

   var fileRootName = file.name.split('.').shift(),
     fileExtension = file.name.split('.').pop(),
     filePathBase = upload_dir + '/',
     fileRootNameWithBase = filePathBase + fileRootName,
     filePath = fileRootNameWithBase + '.' + fileExtension,
     fileID = 2,
     fileBuffer;

   while (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
     filePath = fileRootNameWithBase + '(' + fileID + ').' + fileExtension;
     fileID += 1;
   }

   file.contents = file.contents.split(',').pop(); // removed this when sent contents as blob

   fileBuffer = new Buffer(file.contents, "base64");

   fs.writeFileSync(filePath, fileBuffer);
}
```

What am i missing? How can i write blob contents on file so that it can properly be saved as webm file?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I am doing as below and its working fine:

```
fs.writeFile(
    'path.webm',
    new Buffer(encoder.compile(true)),
    'base64',
    function(e){
        if (e) console.log('fs.writeFile error '+e);
});
```

When not specifying 'base64' at the file creation (not buffer) might be what was wrong.
As you can see, I am using whammy on the server side (just pushing each frame to the encoder).

```
encoder = new Whammy.Video();
encoder.add(data.image, data.duration);
```

I hope this could help you !